# Non-disruptive way of resetting the pod restart count in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Currently our monitoring is designed in a such a way that it alerts if any pod restarts more than 50 times.

This is an example alert we get

```
summary = More than 50 restarts in pod xxx on cluster xxx
```

In some situations because of planned maintenance activities the specific application pods get restarted and the restart count goes more than 50 and subsequently we get alerted.

This alert will be active until the count resets back to 0 again.

So for non-prod environments we delete that pod (with more than 50 restarts) , then the deployment creates a new one and automatically the restart count (for new pod) comes to 0 and we are all happy.

But we dont have that leverage to do the same destructive operation of deleting a pod in production. And we if dont do it, the restart count remains as more than 50 always , alert keeps on coming. And there is also a good chance we loose a genuine alert in between this.

How can we overcome this. I assume this should be the same problem everyone faces in the k8s world.

This is the prometheus metric we use to track the restart count

`kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total > 50`

Tried looking out for k8s documentation to reset the pod counter directly from the k8s etc database, but that doest seem like a recommended approach.

How can we overcome this. What is the best possible approach.

Comment: Why do you consider deleting a pod "destructive"?  Normally its controlling Deployment or StatefulSet will recreate it immediately.  I might suggest tooling like `kubectl rollout restart deployment ...` which will delete and recreate all of a Deployment's Pods in one fell swoop.

Comment: @DavidMaze as we all know , any change in production that impacts the app availability goes through lot of approvals and scrutiny. In this case if we are trying to do a rollout restart - thats technically a new deployment in production and Which practically makes things im-possible.

Comment: Assuming you have more than one replica (you do, right?) neither deleting individual Pods nor `kubectl rollout restart` should significantly affect availability.  The Service will continue to route requests to the Pods that are still running.  The Deployment-restart sequence will only recreate some of the Pods at a time, waiting to destroy old ones until new ones pass their liveness and readiness probes.

Comment: Keep in mind that in Kubernetes pod restart is equal to pod delete. Pods are supposed to be mortal and temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be accomplish by restarting the pod.

Also, a feature related to this has been rejected.

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50375